# index error: index out of range, It shouldnt be out of range though, i tried tracing it

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

This is a code for encrypting the message like you do in playfair cipher.

```
def encrypt(input_message):
    r1=r2=c1=c2=0
    play = playfair()
    listed_ip = list(input_message)
    j=1
    listed_op=list('#####################################################################################################################################################')
    for i in range(len(listed_ip)-1):
        first_letter = listed_ip[i]
        second_letter = listed_ip[j]
        if first_letter =='j':
            listed_ip[i] = 'i'
        if second_letter == 'j':
            listed_ip[j] = 'i'
        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(5):
                if play[row][col] ==first_letter:
                    r1=row
                    c1=col
                if play[row][col] == second_letter:
                    r2=row
                    c2=col
            if r1 == r2:
                listed_op[i] = play[r1][(c1+1)%5]
                listed_op[j] = play[r2][(c2 + 1) % 5]
            elif c1 ==c2:
                listed_op[i] = play[(r1+1)%5][c1]
                listed_op[j] = play[(r2+1)%5][c2]
            else:
                listed_op[i]=play[r1][c2]
                listed_op[j]=play[r2][c1]
            i+=2
            j+=2
    output_text = ''.join(listed_op)
    print(output_text)
encrypt('Hithisisvishal')
```

I am supposed to get an output that changes this input message where evry letter is replaced with another letter according to its position in a matrix.

The other function where the matrix in which the position of each letter is checked with is:

```
import numpy as np


def playfair():
    key = input('Enter the key :')
    key += 'abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
    size = len(key)
    listed_key=list(key)

    for i in range(size):
        if listed_key[i] == 'j':
            listed_key[i] = 'i'
        for j in range(i+1, size):
            if listed_key[j] == listed_key[i]:
                for k in range(j, size-1):
                    listed_key[k] = listed_key[k+1]
                size -= 1
            else : j += 1
    final_key = ''.join(listed_key)
    play = np.zeros((5, 5), 'U1')

    play.flat[:32] = list(final_key)
    return play
```

The error i am getting is:

```
Enter the keysecc

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-dd6ef9446893> in <module>
     33     output_text = ''.join(listed_op)
     34     print(output_text)
---> 35 encrypt('Hithisisvishal')

<ipython-input-6-dd6ef9446893> in encrypt(input_message)
      7     for i in range(len(listed_ip)-1):
      8         first_letter = listed_ip[i]
----> 9         second_letter = listed_ip[j]
     10         if first_letter =='j':
     11             listed_ip[i] = 'i'

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your i and j are not correctly assigned.

```
for i in range(len(listed_ip)-1):
```

The variable i will be 0, 1, 2, ... After you set i += 2, it will be reset when it loops back. The variable j is updated inside the second for loop.  Therefore, you have index error.

```
def encrypt(input_message):
    r1 = r2 = c1 = c2 = 0
    play = playfair()
    listed_ip = list(input_message)
    j = 1
    listed_op = list('#'*150)

    for i in range(0, len(listed_ip)-1, 2):
        j = i + 1
        first_letter = listed_ip[i]
        second_letter = listed_ip[j]
        if first_letter == 'j':
            listed_ip[i] = 'i'
        if second_letter == 'j':
            listed_ip[j] = 'i'
        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(5):
                if play[row][col] == first_letter:
                    r1 = row
                    c1 = col
                if play[row][col] == second_letter:
                    r2 = row
                    c2 = col
            if r1 == r2:
                listed_op[i] = play[r1][(c1+1) % 5]
                listed_op[j] = play[r2][(c2 + 1) % 5]
            elif c1 == c2:
                listed_op[i] = play[(r1+1) % 5][c1]
                listed_op[j] = play[(r2+1) % 5][c2]
            else:
                listed_op[i] = play[r1][c2]
                listed_op[j] = play[r2][c1]
            # i += 2
            # j += 2
    output_text = ''.join(listed_op)
    print(output_text)
```

Comment: Your code did not handle the case: "If both letters are the same (or only one letter is left), add an "X" after the first letter. Encrypt the new pair and continue. Some variants of Playfair use "Q" instead of "X", but any letter, itself uncommon as a repeated pair, will do."

Comment: message = 'Hello'
message = message.lower()
message2 = []

for i in range(0, len(message)-1, 2):
    message2.append(message[i])
    if message[i] == message[i+1]:
        message2.append('x')
    message2.append(message[i+1])
if len(message2) % 2 != 0:
    message2.append('x')

Comment: Yes, i did forget that condition and the j error too. Thanks a lot dude. It works fine now with little editing.

Comment: But in the code add 'x' in case letters are repeated it doesnt add the last letter if the message has odd number of letters.In this case 'Hello' becomes ['h', 'e', 'l', 'x', 'l', 'x']

Comment: In the for loop i doesnt reach the last alphabet as its exclusive in range but if i not use len()-1 i get the out of index error again bcz [i+1] exceeds

Comment: message = 'Hello'
message = message.lower()
message2 = []

for i in range(0, len(message)-1, 2):
    message2.append(message[i])
    if message[i] == message[i+1]:
        message2.append('x')
    message2.append(message[i+1])

if len(message) % 2 != 0:
    message2.append(message[-1])
if len(message2) % 2 != 0:
    message2.append('x')

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your problem is that your j value is getting too big for the array. Currently your j value is increasing by ten for every element in listed_ip. At that rate, it only needs two iterations to exceed the length of listed_ip and throw an IndexError. A possible fix for this would be setting your j value to 1 inside the for loop rather than before it. That way for every value in listed_ip, you start with j=1.

Heres my fix:

```
def encrypt(input_message):
    r1=r2=c1=c2=0
    play = playfair()
    listed_ip = list(input_message)
    print(listed_ip)
    
    listed_op=list('#####################################################################################################################################################')
    for i in range(len(listed_ip)-1):
        j=1
        first_letter = listed_ip[i]
        second_letter = listed_ip[j]
        if first_letter =='j':
            listed_ip[i] = 'i'
        if second_letter == 'j':
            listed_ip[j] = 'i'
        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(5):
                if play[row][col] ==first_letter:
                    r1=row
                    c1=col
                if play[row][col] == second_letter:
                    r2=row
                    c2=col
            if r1 == r2:
                listed_op[i] = play[r1][(c1+1)%5]
                listed_op[j] = play[r2][(c2 + 1) % 5]
            elif c1 ==c2:
                listed_op[i] = play[(r1+1)%5][c1]
                listed_op[j] = play[(r2+1)%5][c2]
            else:
                listed_op[i]=play[r1][c2]
                listed_op[j]=play[r2][c1]
            i+=2
            j+=2
    output_text = ''.join(listed_op)
    print(output_text)
encrypt('Hithisisvishal')
```

Its just a change to that one line, see if it works for you